# AR Core Persistent Cloud Anchors - Time To Live

Tags: google-cloud-platform, arcore

Is it possible to set an expiration time (anchor property *expireTime*) later than the maximum expiration time (anchor property *maximumExpireTime*) indicated when fetching the anchor info using the Cloud Anchors Management API?

This may at first sound like a stupid question, but please continue reading.

I have Persistent Cloud Anchors setup and working in an Android app, ie. I can create anchors with a Time To Live (TTL) over one day. The documentation of Cloud Anchors says that you can set a TTL of 1-365 days, and that the expiration time can be changed afterwards using the Cloud Anchors Management API.

The thing is, the Cloud Anchors Management API happily receives an updated *expireTime* later than *maximumExpireTime* without complaining and when fetching the anchor info again, it clearly indicates that the anchor has an *expireTime* later than *maximumExpireTime*.

Note: *maximumExpireTime* seems to be fixed 365 days after *createTime*

Anyone with experience of persistent cloud anchors and their TTL or with insight of the inner workings of the service? I think that a *maximumExpireTime* of 365 days after *createTime* is a bit short to qualify as **persistent**. It should be more like 365 days after *lastLocalizeTime*, which effectively would expire any anchor that hasn't been used for up until a year.

Comment: It's the same situation for me — it happily sets the expireDate to 2030 even though the documentation clearly states it's at most one year. Since this question is now one year old — are your old markers still valid? :)

Comment: I had totally forgotten about this, it didn't get much response… We dropped the idea of using AR Core Cloud Anchors, the support (and functionality) was too limited (is it still?).

Comment: Anyway, out of curiosity I did a check and found this:  
    "createTime": "2021-04-21T14:00:00Z"
    "expireTime": "2024-04-22T15:00:00Z"  
    "lastLocalizeTime": "2021-04-21T15:00:00Z"  
    "maximumExpireTime": "2022-04-21T15:00:00Z"  
So yes, it lived for longer than 365 days after creation date. It's actually alive  ~2.5 years since lastLocalizeTime even though maximumExpireTime was passed  ~1.5 years ago. I don't know if it's possible to extend the expireTime though…

Comment: Well, I was able to extend the expireTime, but I don't know if it's still possible to use it for localization… In my opinion, the service is still confusing and/or broken.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, I'm gonna be considering using Azure Anchors instead. This really seems like an incomplete service with poor documentation anyway